# How to get subject value from cts:triples output

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am executing below query to get the list of triples from `"testCollection"` where predicate is `"testName"`.

```
cts:triples((), sem:iri("testName"), (), (), (), cts:and-query(cts:collection-query("testCollection"))).
```

I can see the result in qconsole as below.

```
<a> <testName> <aa> .
<b> <testName> <bb> .
<c> <testName> <cc> .
<d> <testName> <dd> .
<e> <testName> <ee> .
```

My requirement is to get the `subject / object` values from the result.

for example, let's say if I want to get the values of `subject`, then output should be as below,

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

and for `object` output should be as below,

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Your example, using `cts` functions, I would use the items related to that: `sem:triple-subject()` and `sem:triple-object()`

Please keep in mind that IRIs and Strings are not the same.. Your data has IRIs and your expected result is string.  I present a sample that matches what You state that You want:

```
    xquery version "1.0-ml";

    (:

      Sample Output based on docs  - sem triples
      Also, your data suggests that all items are IRIs
    :)
    let $triples := (
      sem:triple(sem:iri("a"), sem:iri("testName"), sem:iri("aa")),
      sem:triple(sem:iri("b"), sem:iri("testName"), sem:iri("bb")),
      sem:triple(sem:iri("c"), sem:iri("testName"), sem:iri("cc"))
    )

    return for $triple in $triples
     return fn:string-join((xs:string(sem:triple-subject($triple)), xs:string(sem:triple-object($triple))), ",")
```

In this case, I cast as xs:string() to match your expected output and  joined the subject and object by a comma for display purposes.

```
a,aa
b,bb
c,cc
```

But what about full IRIs:
`sem:triple(sem:iri("c"), sem:iri("testName"), sem:iri("http://www.example.com#cc"))`

The result of that result would be:
`c, http://www.example.com#cc`

I'll not take that further - just wanted to point out that you should be aware of what is actually behind an IRI since your sample was simplified.

Lastly, I would probably write a more specific SPARQL query to return just the subject and object and use `xdmp:sparql()` or `op:from-sparql()` if I were not in the cts space for my work already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`sem:triple-object()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/sem:triple-object) and [`sem:triple-subject()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/sem:triple-subject) functions to return just the object or the subject.

```
for $triple in cts:triples((), sem:iri("testName"), (), (), (), cts:collection-query("testCollection"))
return sem:triple-object($triple)
```